# Azure devops failing to build visual studio sql database project: SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a sql database project in Visual Studio  (2019).
I am trying to deploy it via azure devops.

The pipeline is failing due to the below error:

*##[error]C:\azagent\A1_work\r1\a_Transcripts-SQLDeployment\SampleDatabaseProject\SampleDatabaseProject\SampleDatabaseProject.sqlproj(117,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk*

The project builds without issue on my pc.
In the pipeline I have tried both the MSBuild and Visual Studio Build tasks, but the result is the same in each case.

**Steps tried:**

I found the reference in the sqlproj file xml, and removed it but this did not resolve the issue.

Appreciate any expertise on how to resolve this.

Comment: The error message is telling you the exact problem: Your build agent doesn't have a required dependency on it. Install the appropriate version of SSDT on your build agent.

Comment: I understand this. I have been unable to find out how to ensure the dependency is available in the azure devops build agent.